# ¿Cómo imprimir desde la web en una impresora térmica local conectada por usb utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, imprimir, impresora, slim3

He estado con este problema durante varios días, comentaré mi situación:
estoy haciendo un sistema de pedidos online, donde una vez creado un pedido se activa la impresión del ticket. He intentado usar Google Cloud Print, imprime pero lleva mucho tiempo y no funciona como debería, probé una biblioteca llamada mike42, imprime perfecto pero no desde un sitio web. El sistema está en un hosting y estoy usando PHP junto con slim 3, si alguno de ustedes sabe cómo solucionar esto se lo agradecería mucho.

El código se ejecuta en el capa de negocio (OrderService), aca lo que hace es recibir el pedido y el nombre de la impresora,  lo arma en el ticket y lo imprime. Necesitaria esto mismo pero que se pueda imprimir desde un sitito web donde esta alojado el sistema.
El resultado que quiero (para ser mas especifico) es el siguiente:  El usuario empleado se loguea en la web (sistema alojado en el hosting), va al menu pedidos, cuando aprieta en crear el pedido se ejecute esta function e imprime el ticket directamente en la impresora termica conectada a la maquina local.
Esto mismo anda solo si la web esta en el servidor local, cosa que no es lo que quiero.

```
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer; 
use App\CrossCutting\Constants\PaymentMethods;

    class PrinterHelper 
    {
    /** 
     * Prints an order ticket
     *
     * @param array $order
         * @param string $printerName
     *
     * @return boolean
    */
    public static function PrintTicket ($order, $printerName)
    {
                $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector($printerName);
                $printer = new Printer($connector);

                $currentDateTime = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');

                $printer->text($currentDateTime . ' orden: ' . $order['orderNumber'] . "\n");
                $printer->text(''. "\n");

                foreach ($order['products'] as $product)
                {
                        $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);

                        if (!$product['hasFlavors'])
                        {
                                if (empty($product['subProducts']))
                                {
                                        $printer->text($product['name'] . ' x ' . $product['quantity'] . "\n");
                                        
                                        if (!is_null($product['comments']) && !empty($product['comments']))
                                        {
                                                $printer->text($product['comments'] .  "\n");
                                        }
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                        $printer->text($product['name'] . ' x ' . $product['quantity'] . "\n");

                                        foreach ($product['subProducts'] as $subProduct)
                                        {
                                                $printer->text('    ' . $subProduct['name'] . "\n");

                                                if ($subProduct['hasFlavors'])
                                                {
                                                        foreach ($subProduct['flavors'] as $flavor)
                                                        {
                                                                $printer->text('    ' . $flavor['abbreviation'] . "\n");
                                                        }

                                                        if (!is_null($subProduct['comments']) && !empty($subProduct['comments']))
                                                        {
                                                                $printer->text($subProduct['comments'] .  "\n");
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                $printer->text($product['name'] . "\n");

                                foreach ($product['flavors'] as $flavor)
                                {
                                        $printer->text('    ' . $flavor['abbreviation'] . "\n");
                                }

                                if (!is_null($product['comments']) && !empty($product['comments']))
                                {
                                        $printer->text($product['comments'] .  "\n");
                                }
                        }                                       
                }

                $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
                $printer->text('' . "\n");
                $printer->setTextSize(2, 2);
                $printer->text($order['cellphone'] . "\n");
                $printer->text($order['address'] . "\n");
                $printer->setTextSize(1, 2);
                
                switch ($order['paymentMethodId']) {
                        case PaymentMethods::ID1:
                                $printer->text($order['cost'] . "\n"); 
                        break;
                        
                        case PaymentMethods::ID2:
                                $printer->text(PaymentMethods::MERCADOPAGOLINK . "\n");
                                $printer->text($order['cost'] . "\n");
                        break;

                        case PaymentMethods::ID3:
                                $printer->text(PaymentMethods::ENVIARPOSNET . "\n");
                        break;
                }
                
                $printer->feed(3);
                $printer->cut();
                $printer->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cómo se activa la impresión del ticket? QUé código lo lleva a cabo? Cómo intentaste usar mike42? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade la información relevante; no es claro lo que intentas hacer y eso nos impide ayudarte de forma efectiva

Comment: Desde PHP no vas a poder imprimir en el cliente, debes buscar otra opción, tal vez generar el ticket y hacer que el usuario lo descargue y luego lo imprima. O probar algo en Javascript, como esto: https://github.com/parzibyte/plugin-ticket-js

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.  Alfinal decidi hacerlo localmente, pero sincronizando la base de datos del hosting con la local y listo :P